# React native not calling Android native method from parent app

Tags: javascript, react-native, redis

I am trying to get my react native redis module up and running,
but getting following error. when i try to refer to any function

```js
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeRedispubsub.RedisClient.redisConnect')
```

RedisClient.js

```js
/**
 * This exposes our Android code into our RN project
 */

import { NativeModules } from "react-native";
module.exports = NativeModules.RedisClient;
```

File that has actual redis calls via redison jar
RedisClient.java

```js
package com.redispubsub;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.redisson.Redisson;
import org.redisson.api.RTopic;
import org.redisson.api.RedissonClient;
import org.redisson.api.listener.MessageListener;
import org.redisson.client.RedisConnectionException;
import org.redisson.client.codec.StringCodec;
import org.redisson.config.Config;


public class RedisClient extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
  private final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;
  private RedissonClient mredissonClient;

  public RedisClient(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    this.reactContext = reactContext;
  }
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "RedisClient";
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void redisConnect(String ipPort) {
    //Redisson client setup to be done in background thread
    try {
      
      Config config = new Config();
      config.useSingleServer().setAddress(ipPort); //IPAddress of Redis and port
      mredissonClient = Redisson.create(config);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void subscribe(String channelName) {

    if (mredissonClient != null) {
      RTopic subscribeTopic = mredissonClient.getTopic(channelName, StringCodec.INSTANCE); //Channel to listen and Codec.
      subscribeTopic.addListener(new MessageListener < String > () {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(String channel, String msg) {
          reactContext
            .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
            .emit(channel, msg);
        }
      });
    } else {

    }

  }

  @ReactMethod
  public long publish(String ChannelName, String msg) {
    long clientsReceivedMessage = 0;
    if (mredissonClient != null) {
      //Redisson publish
      RTopic topic = mredissonClient.getTopic(ChannelName, StringCodec.INSTANCE);
      try {

        clientsReceivedMessage = topic.publish(msg); //Publishing lat lon to Coros
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    } else {

    }
    return clientsReceivedMessage;

  }


}
```

Exposing the methods to java script 
RedisCleintPackage.java

```js
package com.redispubsub;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;

public class RedisClientPackage implements ReactPackage {
  @Override
  public List < NativeModule > createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    List < NativeModule > modules = new ArrayList < > ();

    modules.add(new RedisClient(reactContext));

    return modules;
  }

  public List < Class << ? extends JavaScriptModule >> createJSModules() {
    return Arrays.asList();
  }

  @Override
  public List < ViewManager > createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();

  }
}
```

does this _reactNativeRedispubsub.RedisClient.redisConnect means its not getting to right object to call ?

I am confused as to why its not picking up the redisConnect which is there in the RedisClient.java

this entire code is working in my react-native android project where i have MainActivity running, but dosent work when i publish it to npm and get it my npm install

Comment: can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

I got it

following change needs to be done in 
redisclient.js

/**
 * This exposes our Android code into our RN project
 */

```
import { NativeModules } from "react-native";

const { RedisClient } = NativeModules;

export {
  RedisClient
}
```

Comment: could you post the project link?

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
module.exports = NativeModules.RedisClient;
```